# Adjust postion only in X axis

Tags: unity, transformation, linear-algebra

I have two game objects named `A` and `B`, just as follows:

[image]

I want to move object `B` to this virtual line without any rotation so that the destination is `B'` . What I have are transformation of object `A` and `B`. I'm brand new to Unity3D and its APIs, so I don't know how should I get this done.

Comment: You want to translate object B towards the red line or just instantaneously place it on the red line ??

Comment: I want to project/translate B onto the line.

Comment: @HashBuoy I've edited my question to be more clear. Please take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest and non mathematical (noob) way to do this is to make Game object B a child of Game object A , then make local position x as zero and remove B from the parent A.

```
B.transform.parent = A.transform;
B.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (0, B.transform.localPosition.y, B.transform.localPosition.z);
B.transform.parent = null;
```

Comment: Good. I'll add this :  If you use an empty gameobject (like C) you copy B.position to C.position. Then you use C instead of B in your code. So finaly you get C.postion as target for a smooth movement of B.

Comment: No probs :)....